# Can I back up my Windows 7 Installation, change the OS drive letter, then restore it?

Tags: windows-7, backup, drive-letter

I just installed Windows 7 to a new SSD HD and got everything setup how I want it but then realized that the hard drive that the OS was on is the G drive.  I'd like to change it to the C drive but have read that this is not possible.

Is there any way for me to back up this installation and the restore it after I fix the drive letter problem so I don't have to reinstall all my programs and reset all the settings?  Or is any backup I make from the G drive going to be unusable once it's named the C drive?

Comment: I think it depends on whether you backup files only or a full disk image. The full image is sure to fail. But files only might work. If it were me, I would try to backup all files with e.g. Acronis Trueimage... then reinstall OS (which should set the boot drive to C)... then restore the files. No guarantees this goes painlessly.

Comment: Does that backup the installed programs and their settings?

Comment: it backs up the files themselves, but not the registry. If you've ever tried running a program without its registry settings you know it's kind of a tossup if they work or not. The more complex the are, the less likely they are to work. It sucks but I think you may have to reinstall everything or live with the drive letter. Everything I've googled says trying to force the change is going to cause headaches later. Is there currently no C: drive? I'm thinking you could map C: to G:. Kinda goofy though.

Comment: No, my old system drive that has Vista on it is C, I'm going to get rid of that but was waiting until I figured out my strategy for this whole mess.  Is there any reason not to just leave my main drive as G?  Is it just a matter or preference or could could having my os on G cause me problems down the road?

Comment: as far as I know there's no downside to keeping your main drive as G:, at least on a modern computer. I know what you mean, I'd prefer C also just out of habit, but it shouldn't matter really.